# width vs max-width in responsive web design

Tags: width, responsive-design, css

It is recommended in tutorials about responsive web design to use max-width:100% for images to make the flexible. Why can we use width:100% for this purpose ?

Comment: Have you tried both rules?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question and I think this is the answer after doing a little experiment:

`width:100%;` scales the width of an image no matter what happens.

- When `100%` is greater than the original resolution of that image, the image keeps scaling and thus looks blurry.
- When `height` is assigned to that image, the width keeps scaling and thus becomes stretched.

`max-width:100%;` scales the width of an image more carefully.

- When `100%` is greater than the original resolution of that image, the image stops scaling and looks delicate.
- When `height` is assigned to that image, the width stops scaling and keeps the aspect ratio.

So i think this is the reason why people are using `max-width` rather than `width`.

Screen capture of the experiment: [here](http://www.etblue.idv.tw/et/experiment/www.etblue.idv.tw-et-experiment-width.html.png) (the sketch image is 600 px * 432 px)

Web page of the experiment: [here](http://www.etblue.idv.tw/et/experiment/width.html)

Answer (score 1):

Smaller images, for example image 200px wide would be always extended to the width of parent container, which can be be much wider on bigger screens. As a result you'd end up with upscaled images, which rarely look good, due to visible artifacts.