# Inner div floats out of parent div

Tags: html, css

[Example](http://gyazo.com/6a9873648062ab1a8777a20ecee9986e)

There is a margin-bottom set for each `sidebar-block` of `10px`, it appears as the inner div which is `sidebar-block.body` is flowing out of the container.

I researched and debugged and cannot find the cause for this, the only time I use floats is on the main `#sidebar` itself.

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-block">
        <div class="sidebar-block title"><div class="text-with-margin">profile</div></div>
        <div class="sidebar-block body"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-block">
            <div class="sidebar-block title"><div class="text-with-margin">forum activity</div> </div>
        <div class="sidebar-block body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 268px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sidebar-block {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sidebar-block.title {
    background-color: #2E392F;
    min-height: 47px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.sidebar-block.body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

.text-with-margin {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I could not able to understand your problem.

Comment: @sємsєм oh sorry I tried to explain it as best as I could.

Comment: I've run you code and everything seems to works fine. Tell more about your problem. What you whant to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/fvjw5/

Comment: @estshy there has to be a bottom margin of 10px between each sidebar block. It also adds the margin to the title div, is that because I am using sidebar-block in all the divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, it was because I used .sidebar-block title, .sidebar-block body in a way so that the css for .sidebar-block would automatically be applied to them, not my intention so I renamed the divs.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment. Change your code for that

```
 #sidebar > .sidebar-block 
 {
     margin-bottom: 10px; 
 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fvjw5/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the maximum width of the Sidebar element.
As it is, the Sidebar element does not have a fixed size, which will nullify the

```
.text-with-margin {
     width: 100%; // The width. You should change this.
     ...
}
```

See this post for information about position: [CSS Positions](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

You should try something like:

```
#sidebar {
    width: 100%; // Or whatever size you want the sidebar to be.
    position: relative; // You can play with this for different results.
    ...
}
```

You can look at the information provided on the answer below:
[Responsive web design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826248/width-vs-max-width-in-responsive-web-design)